# How many five-fold axes in a quasi-crystal?

Tags: symmetry, crystals, quasicrystals, quasi-periodic

For simplicity, let us consider the 2D case. Suppose O is a five-fold axis or point. If $P_0$ is another five-fold axis, then by the rotation symmetry around O, we can get in total five five-fold axes, $\{ P_0, P_1, P_2, P_3, P_4\}$. Now we can rotate the system around these five points, and we will generate many more extra five-fold axes.

Intuitively, by the process, we can generate a dense set of five-fold axes.

Does this mean a quasi-crystal can have only one five-fold axis? Is this true or not?